Newly created user not showing in user DB?
I'm using AWS 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.05.2
I do this on an DB console (connected via DBeaver app).
use mysql;
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED by 'password123';
flush privileges;

and get feedback that user is created, i.e., no errors. But then when I do
SELECT user,host FROM user;

or
SELECT user,host FROM user WHERE user like 'my_u%';

and I don't see the user? What's going on?

If you just do SELECT user, host FROM user; do you see it?

No, I don't see it. I tried that too.

Sorry I corrected the post. It's just IDENTIFIED by 'password123'

I can't see any reason for this. Do you see other users when you list the whole table?

I know, it's baffling! And yes I do see other users.

BTW, you don't need flush privileges. That's only needed when you modify the tables directly instead of using commands like CREATE USER.

Hmmm, I do see 'my_user' (with the single quotes) in the table. WT...

That's extremely weird. It would only happen if you did CREATE USER "'my_user'"@'%'. I don't use DBeaver, I wonder if it could be doing additional quoting.
